# How to get %BUGID% in post-commit hook script?

Tags: tortoisesvn, integration, svn-hooks, mantis, post-commit-hook

I want to set up Mantis bug tracker and tortoise svn to work together.
I have added properties to tortoise svn like below:
[image]

And also I have added below properties to `config_inc.php` file

```
$g_source_control_notes_view_status = VS_PUBLIC;
$g_source_control_account = 'xxx';
$g_source_control_set_status_to = OFF;
$g_source_control_regexp = "/\bissue [#]{0,1}(\d+)\b/i";
```

And my post-commit.bat looks like

```
SET REPOS=%1
SET REV=%2
SET DETAILS_FILE=\svnfile_%REV%

echo Bug ID : %BUGID%>>%DETAILS_FILE%
svnlook log -r %REV% %REPOS%>>%DETAILS_FILE%
echo SVN Revision:%REV%>>%DETAILS_FILE%

echo Files Changed :  >>%DETAILS_FILE%
svnlook changed -r %REV% %REPOS%>>%DETAILS_FILE%

\php.exe \checkin.php <%DETAILS_FILE% >%LOG_FILE%
```

This works fine if I provide issue ID in commit message.
If I provide issue id in commit message it shows commit message in mantis Notes.

**Issue** Now I Don't want to put issue id in commit message but want to take %BUGID% that I provide in right most upper corner when doing tortoise svn commit.

i.e. `echo Bug ID : %BUGID%>>%DETAILS_FILE%`
it is not working for me.
Can any one help me.

And yes Do anyone know how to add html link or html tags in post-commit hook script.
Thanks in advance.